# Powershell - Trying to get a blank line when an error is present

Tags: powershell

I am trying to have a blank line created in the output when an error is found. Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
$list = ForEach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) {
    Get-Mailbox  $mailbox | select primarysmtpaddress
    If (ErrorAction == $True) { Write-Output `n}
}
```

`$mailboxes` is assigned to a get-content command that is working perfectly. The select primarysmtpaddress is also working correctly. The If statement and the code inside it is not.

EDIT: Corrected 'n with the correct escape character of `n

Comment: Hey jisaak! I tried doing the four spaces before the code. How did you get it to show up correctly?

Comment: Just mark the code and format it using the `{}` within the editior ;-)

Comment: @ArthurMarquis The standard way to mark a question on StackOverflow as answered is to *Accept* one of the answers by clicking the check mark below the voting buttons.  There is no need to put it in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're saving to a variable you can't use `Write-Host`, but you could return an empty string. `Select primarysmptpaddress` returns a `pscustomobject` with a `primarysmtpaddress`-property. Since we return a blank string on error, I would use `-ExpandProperty primar...` to only get the string value inside so we have the same type of object on success and failure.

```
$list = ForEach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) { 
    #Try/Catch to catch errors
    try {
        #Added -ErrorAction Stop to make sure it goes to catch on error. Might not be necessary (depends on the cmdlet).
        #Used ExpandProperty to only get the value of primarysmptaddress as a string (since no mail = empty string in catch-block)
        Get-Mailbox $mailbox -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty primarysmtpaddress
    } catch {
        #Blank value. Can't use Write-Host / Out-Host since you're saving to a variable
        ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Frode F. this has worked perfectly. I did not try without the -ErrorAction Stop so I was unable to determine if it was necessary or not. Thank you very much for taking the time to help out a powershell noobie! I will edit the post to mark it as answered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a `try` and a `catch`, and write the empty line in the catch.

You are also using an incorrect escape character: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html

```
ForEach ($mailbox in $mailboxes)
{
    try
    {
        Get-Mailbox  $mailbox | select primarysmtpaddress
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host `n
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try now!

Comment: Didn't seem to work, still got the list like normal Here is the exact code I used.                                                                                                                    
`$list = foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) { try { Get-Mailbox     $mailbox | select primarySMTPaddress} catch { Write-Host `n}}

Sorry I am still not getting the code formatting correct. I will work on it.